# Count files and subfolders in directory

Tags: php, recursion, directory, counting

I am writing a script which counts all files and folders recursively. I tried two approaches but each of these returns a different value:
Script 1: 2376
Script 2: 2178

Here are the two scripts:

```
$source = 'folder';
$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($source), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
foreach($files as $file) {
    $result[] = $file.'<br />';
}
echo count($result).'<br />';
    function listFolders($dir) {
    if($dh = opendir($dir)) {
        $files = Array();
        $inner_files = Array();
        while($file = readdir($dh)) {
            if($file != "." && $file != "..") {
                if(is_dir($dir . "/" . $file)) {
                    $inner_files = listFolders($dir . "/" . $file);
                    if(is_array($inner_files)) $files = array_merge($files, $inner_files); 
                } else {
                    array_push($files, $dir . "/" . $file);
                }
            }
        }
        closedir($dh);
        return $files;
    }
}
foreach (listFolders($source) as $key=>$file){
    $result2[] = $file ."<br />";
}
echo count($result2);
```

Is one of the scripts correct? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your first example with RecursiveIterator, you are also counting the dot directories. In your second example, you cut them out.

Use this:

```
$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($source, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS), RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);
foreach($files as $file) {

    $result[] = $file.'<br />';
}
```

Comment: I got this: "Fatal error: Call to undefined method SplFileInfo::isDot() in /home/gtsvetan/public_html/files.php on line 10" my php version is: 5.2.17

Comment: You shouldn't be using a PHP version which reached end-of-life two years ago. There is literally NO bug fixing going on in the 5.2 branch, not even important security fixes.

Comment: Updated code, take a look. Uses FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS constant instead of the isDot() method which isnt a valid method of recursiveiteratoriterator

Comment: I fix this and the error is mine... But when I try with isDot() the result is the same: first script -> 8133 / second script -> 7422

Comment: When I run php 5.3 and add FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS the result is: 69

Comment: Yeah, its an inconsistency, since RecursiveIteratorIterator will only cont leaves, not parents and children. You could add RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST after RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($source), FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);

Comment: I think there is an issue with your second function. I'm debugging now.

Comment: Something like that? $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($source, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS), RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);